# Open zip and read contents

Tags: php, view, zip

I have a little php, application or whatever that opens a zip and reads the content. But it only works SOME of the time... sometimes when I upload the .zip and try to view contents, it works and echos back each file to me, but some other times ( yes i have a lot of .zip files ), it returns these errors:

```
Warning: zip_read() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given in /home/blah/public_html/templates.php on line 23

Warning: zip_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given in /home/blah/public_html/templates.php on line 31
```

Here is my code:

```
$open = zip_open($file);
while($zip = zip_read($open)) {
$file = zip_entry_name($zip);
echo $file.'<br />';
}
zip_close($open);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The cases where that happens are cases when the Zip file can not be opened.

`Zip_open()` returns an integer instead of the file handle when it encounters an error. [**Documentation**](https://www.php.net/zip_open)

> Returns a resource handle for later use with zip_read() and zip_close()  or returns the number of error if filename  does not exist or in case of other error.

You need to output `$open` and check what error code it gives you. You should build this into the code as a fixed check before trying to run any zip operations.

[**This table**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.constants.php) will tell you which error code means what.

Comment: You should als as a general rule check this some where in the code an abort instead of jsut expecting it to be ok.

Comment: A simple check might be if(is_numeric($open)){//fail}else{while....}

Answer (score 2):

```
$open = zip_open($file);

if (is_numeric($open)) {
    echo "Zip Open Error #: $open";
   } else {
   while($zip = zip_read($open)) {
   .....
   }
```